# Azure : Add a role to a client_secret for an App Registrations

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-rbac

I'm not comfortable with azure configuration.

We have an **app registration**, that is configured with roles, group and users.

Everything is ok, but our security policy enforce MFA for connexion. That's a trouble for our automated tests.

Following [that post](https://mechanicalrock.github.io/2020/05/05/azure-ad-authentication-cypress.html) **we created a client secret** Using App Registrations//Certficates & Secrets.
[image]
Authentication is ok, and I can get a token when using postman but no role is assign.

The problem is that I can't figure how to add a role for that client secret !

Can you help ?

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Answer (score 0):

You assign roles to **users, groups, service principals, or managed identities** at a particular scope.

To assign roles from the Azure portal:

1. Browse to Subscriptions blade.
2. Select your Subscription.
3. Go to **Access control (IAM)**.
4. Select Add role assignments and select the **Role** you wish to assign.
5. Search for your App Registration/Service Principal.
6. Save.

[image: Add role assignment]

Note that as a prerequisite to be able to assign Azure roles, you must have `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` permissions, such as [User Access Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator) or [Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#owner).

Check [Assign Azure roles using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal) for more details.

Comment: This is not what he asked

Answer (score 0):

After you generated your secret you need to go to de roles editor in your app registrations and add change member types to **Both (Users/Groups + Applications)**

Then go to **API permissions** and add Application Permissions under your app and add your Role.

Grant Consent.

And its ready, you can now login using your secret and get a token that has the role you need.